# how to use md-tooltip with text that contains break lines (\n) Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

im working on a front end that is running angular js, and I have issue with md-tooltip.

in my html:

```
<md-tooltip>{{ item }}</md-tooltip>
```

and the item text is a string that contains `\n` to have the string break lines (`val tooltipText: String = "1. do this \n 2. do that"`), but I dont get the break line effect, why is that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you should use `<br/>` because the text you set to `md-tooltip` is seperated to multiple `span`s.

Also you have to change the class `md-tooltip` because it's height property is setted to `22px` we can change it to `auto`;

```
.md-tooltip {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

**[Live Example](https://codepen.io/marrypen/pen/qmKzMw)**(check the **Insert Drive** checkbox to see the tooltip with breakline).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space: pre-line;` on your custom class, instead of putting `<br />` inside the text